# How to change dynamically a js function parameter that has json format?

Tags: javascript, php, json, jquery-datatables-editor

I am using editor from the DataTables jQuery plug-in and I have created a table from the generator provided on the site (https://editor.datatables.net/generator/index).
Within the created files, there is a JavaScript file, `table.table_name.js`, which is responsible for the creation of the table. In this file there is a function that takes JSON as a parameter.

Now, I don't want this info to be constant, but to change dynamically, according to new inputs to another database table. So, I have created a PHP file that accesses that table (with the new inputs) and stores its data in a string variable in JSON format.

My question is how can I use that variable in the JS file and give it as a parameter to the function mentioned above? Or is there a better way to change the parameter dynamically?

part of the js function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
    "ajax": "php/table.manage.php",
    "table": "#manage",
    "fields": [
        {
            "label": "Node",
            "name": "node",
            "type": "select",
            "ipOpts": [
                {
                    "label": "",     //here you can see the JSON format
                    "value": ""                   
                }
            ]
```

my php code:

```
$output = '';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($nodes)) {

            $output .='{<br />
            "label": "'.$row['Desc'].'",
            <br />
            "value": "'.$row['Desc'].'" 
            <br />},<br />';      //here i create a JSON formatted string

};
```

I want to use the variable $output insted of the label-value pair in the js function.

Comment: What you are asking is more that changing the value of a parameter. You want the table to be updated, if I am not mistaken. If that's the case, you should look up update methods in the documentation of your plugin.

Also, can you show some more code ? like your function signature and some sample parameters ?

Comment: The first table is being updated independently. What I want is the second table, that I created through the generator, to change, due to these updates. Specifically, I want the user to be able to create new entries in the second table, and the more data the first table has, the more entry options the user has with the second table.